# How can I use EMGU in .NET2 project

Tags: .net, opencv, .net-2.0, emgucv

I'm using .NET2

I need to use EMGU library in my project.

But when i try to attach EMGU DLL's I get this massage:

[image]

How I can understand .NET2 doesn't support EMGU.

Any ideas how can I use EMGU in .NET2 project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: not sure you can you can use emgu with .net 2.0. But why are you stuck with .NET 2.0? You would likely have issues with lots of libs , Emgu aside.

Answer (score 0):

`Emgu CV 2.0` requires `.NET 3.5` at least

[Emgu Version History](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History#Emgu.CV-2.0.0.0_Alpha)

Comment: The first example project has been written in VS2005, .NET2.
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page